# Debug iOS app on iPhone without a developer subscription

Tags: ios, iphone, iphone-developer-program

Is there a way to debug my iOS app on my iPhone without a developer subscription?

As far as I can see there is not, for there is no link to register a device at https://developer.apple.com/account/#/welcome

Comment: You can use a free registration, but you are limited to a single device and a limited number of provisioning profiles per 7 days

Comment: How do I do that? I've just signed up, but I see no way to register a device.